# Remove from closed the following question

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

The following question was closed because it was not in English language as per this site's requirement. I have translated the following question from Urdu to English so i kindly ask the moderators to vote it to open again. Thank you

[homosexuality choice or natural?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16596/4510)

Comment: Editing a closed question puts it in a reopen queue, please don't I add a new meta post every time you translate a post.

Comment: @Mhmd sorry i did not know that. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3):

It is in English now but it is still not a good question since it looks like it is just asking for advice instead of being a question about Islam.  I think it should keep closed.

Comment: I just translated word to word of english now that i read it it can be edited in a better manner to make it a question quality enough for this site